# Password fails when Installing PFX from Remote Win2012 CA on a Win7/2008 machine

Tags: c#, ssl-certificate, x509certificate, ca

I've crafted a WCF service that accesses a remote CA using CERTENROLL and CERTCLIENT libs. My GenerateCertificate request takes a password that's used in the enrollment request. I return metadata about the generated cert and the Base64 string of the raw bytes in the response XML.

If I take the raw cert string and save it as a local .pfx file I can install it easy breezy on a Win10 or 2012 machine. However, when I try it on a Win7 or 2008 machine the password doesn't match.

I'm supplying an X509CertificateRequestCmc request that's intitialized from an inner X509CertificateRequestPkcs10 request which is initialized from a template.

Upon first encountering this error I tried to apply an OS Version CryptAttribute to either one of the request layers without success.

```
CX509AttributeOSVersionClass os = new CX509AttributeOSVersionClass();
os.InitializeEncode("6.1.7601");

CX509AttributesClass attribs = new CX509AttributesClass();
attribs.Add((CX509Attribute)os);

CCryptAttributeClass atty = new CCryptAttributeClass();
atty.InitializeFromValues(attribs);

request.CryptAttributes.Add(atty);
```

I'm only responsible for the WebService tier, I don't have access to the PKI store directly. My dev server app pool has been set to run as an allowed AD account on the PKI server and I don't have that account's password.

Is it me or the store?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I invoked a ticket to MS on this. They said there's a known issue where Base64 pfx files will not install on Win7 & 2008 systems. The answer is to decode the Base64 and install via binary. Careful not to convert to .cer, you'll lose the private key.